# Cast from 'MDLMaterialProperty?!'?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I'm working with the parse framework for an App that I'm converting to Xcode 7.  One of the interesting errors which has occurred as part of migrating the project is the following:

> Cast from 'MDLMaterialProperty?!' to unrelated type 'PFUser' always fails

The offending line seems to be the "if let" clause below.  I've commented the old line which worked fine in the previous version of Swift for comparison.

With respect to what this is actually doing - I've passed an array of Parse objects into "likesForThankful" where a pointer "userID" refers to a related PFUser. As part of this method I'm writing individual PFUsers to an array.

Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance.

```
 //Add PFUsers who Like Post to our FeedItem   
 private func callbackFromLikesProcessing(likesForThankful:[AnyObject], againstFeedItem:FeedItem){

    //Instantiate our Objective C compatible array for processing later
    againstFeedItem.parseUsersObjectsWhoLikePost = NSMutableArray()

    //Loop through likes and add PFUsers to array of users who like post
    for usersWhoLikePost in likesForThankful{
        // if let parseUserWhoLikesPost = usersWhoLikePost["userID"] as PFUser{
        if let parseUserWhoLikesPost = usersWhoLikePost["userID"] as? PFUser {
            againstFeedItem.parseUsersObjectsWhoLikePost.addObject(parseUserWhoLikesPost)
        }
    }
```

Andrew

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured this out if it can help anyone - it's basic Swift Syntax (though I'm not sure why the compiler let me get away with this in the first version of Swift!).

Because usersWhoLikePost is a PFObject which happens to contain a pointer to a PFUser object I needed to conditionally unwrap this first like so:

```
    for usersWhoLikePost in likesForThankful{
        if let parseLikeObject = usersWhoLikePost as? PFObject{
            if let parseUserWhoLikesPost = parseLikeObject["userID"] as? PFUser {
                againstFeedItem.parseUsersObjectsWhoLikePost.addObject(parseUserWhoLikesPost)
            }
        }

    }
```

After this I could continue as I had previously done and access the "userID" property with a conditional unwrap of the PFUser object.

Comment: You know you can just chain your if statements with a comma— you don't have to nest them all like that…

Comment: Running into the same problem after upgrading from 7.1 to 7.2. What used to be an NSDictionary from me parsing JSON data is now apparently an MDLMaterialProperty and it's crashing on everywhere that I cast the elements within the NSDictionary object.

Comment: One significant discovery if you're hitting this with 7.2;  if you use for var in array style loops, this will get you nearly every time.  I've had to convert all of mine to for i in 0..<blah and then assign the variable to the array element.  It's lame, but it works.

Comment: thanks @buildsucceeded absolutely could clean this up but also wanted to preserve readability.